# Make DATETIME column unique through query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following problem: I have a table that has thousands of rows with all the same timestamp. I need every row to have a unique timestamp to be entered in a time series databases. So I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to make a `DATETIME` field unique through a query.

This is what I am working with:

```
2015-09-17 00:00:00.000
2015-09-17 00:00:00.000
2015-09-17 00:00:00.000
2015-09-17 00:00:00.000
2015-09-17 00:00:00.000
2015-09-17 00:00:00.000
```

We have played with the idea of adding to unique id to the milliseconds but .1 and .10 will be the same time. I would like to keep the date as is and manipulate the time to make unique if possible. This query will return 10,000 rows and they all have the same timestamp and they all must somehow become unique.

Comment: Do you have another column that gives you a clue to the relative order of rows? If not, are you happy that we'll be effectively randomly assigning timestamp values?

Comment: rownum/1000, then? that'd make `.001, .002, ... :09.999`

Comment: Does the minute have to stay the same as well (e.g. 00:00:00), or is that free to manipulate as well?

Comment: Can you add a new column and populate it with a GUID using NEWID(). That should make the rows unique. This way you are not altering the time stamp data.

Comment: I have to have a unique timestamp to put the data in a time series data historian. Yes the minutes is free to manipulate. The timestamp is arbitrary in this instance so it can be completely random I would just like to keep the date.

Comment: Unique timestamps are a nightmare.  Seriously, it's one of those "that way lies madness" ideas because you'll need to manipulate timestamps in ways that timestamps aren't meant to be manipulated.  You're trying to make one column do two things here.  Don't do that.  Just use two columns.  I strongly encourage you to create a sequence column of some kind if you need to establish order.

Comment: if you add 1 millisecond to .000, you get .001, not .1, so the idea of adding the unique id will work fine.   Just be sure to use DATEADD, not string manipulation.

Comment: @TabAlleman - unless it's `datetime` rather than `datetime2`, in which case .000 + 1 millisecond is .000 (Because `datetime` can only record milliseconds like .xx0, .xx3, .xx7 and will perform appropriate rounding)

Comment: I wish I didn't have to manipulate the timestamp column but to insert into the time series database it must have a unique timestamp. That become the unique id for that record in a different flat-file database, It has nothing to do with order. How would you auto-increment the DATEADD function so every record of the query has a different timestamp?

Comment: What is the effective type of this timestamp column? `DATETIME`? `DATETIME2`? Another type?

Comment: @TT. It is a datetime.

Comment: whats with the downvote this is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Take this snippet as an example. It tightly increments the source date milliseconds, meaning it uses the minimum increments for `DATETIME` millisecond accuracy (.000, .003, .007).

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(teh_date DATETIME, teh_seq INT IDENTITY(1,1));

INSERT INTO #tt(teh_date)VALUES
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000'),
    ('20150917 00:00:00.000');

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        --rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY teh_seq) --> use this line instead if you have one or more columns you can sort on
    FROM
        #tt
)
SELECT
    teh_date=DATEADD(MS,(CASE (rn-1)%3 WHEN 0 THEN 0 WHEN 1 THEN 3 WHEN 2 THEN 7 END)+((rn-1)/3)*10,teh_date)
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    teh_date;
/* -> use this UPDATE statement instead of the above SELECT if you want to update the source table
UPDATE
    cte
SET 
    teh_date=DATEADD(MS,(CASE (rn-1)%3 WHEN 0 THEN 0 WHEN 1 THEN 3 WHEN 2 THEN 7 END)+((rn-1)/3)*10,teh_date);

SELECT teh_date FROM #tt ORDER BY teh_seq;
*/

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------+
|        teh_date         |
+-------------------------+
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.003 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.007 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.010 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.013 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.017 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.020 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.023 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.027 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.030 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.033 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.037 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.040 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00.043 |
+-------------------------+
```